# What is the most efficient to run certain lines of code only when a boolean is true?

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, maintainability

If I had code that looked like the following:

```
if (bool1) {
    statement1
    statement2
} else if (bool2) {
    statement3
    statement4
}
```

and I only want to run statement 2 and 4 given another boolean (say bool3) is true, what is the best way to format that. I understand that I could add a nested if statement, but that seems bad from a maintainability perspective if I have 5 or more else ifs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can have another if condition for bool3. That is the most efficient I think, So total you will have 3 if condition.
Having 5 if statement is not wrong, unless it's clear to understand and fall in false traps.

Answer (score 0):

A nested if sounds perfectly fine to me at least. If none of the statements mess with bool1, bool3 and bool4 though and you really don't want to use nested ifs you could put them after eachother with conjunctions:

```
if (bool1) {
    statement1
}
if (bool1 && bool3) {
    statement2
}
if (bool2 && !bool1) {
    statement3
}
if (bool2 && !bool1 && bool3) {
    statement4
}
```

This looks terrible though so I'd just go with a plain and simple nested if.